# C# WinForms Design Mode

Tags: c#, .net

Hi i'm trying to figure out how Design Mode functionality works. I make a decomposition of my current task and first of all i have to add right click special handling on a controls which located on IRootDesigner control.

I tryed to read MSDN articles like (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171818.aspx) but there tons of classes and interfaces like :

- IComponentChangeService
- ISelectionService
- Adorner
- Glyph
- BehaviorService
- Site
- IDesigner

and so on and on...

the purposes of each in separate (from MSDN description) i can understand but the main idea and how its works i can't.

Is there any good articles with code examples or may be video lessons to get the main idea how it all works.

Comment: I think u don't understand the question, have u ever work with all this kitchen (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171820.aspx)

Comment: ?Kitchen?! LOL, yes, sure. No, I didn't understand your question. If you meant creating custom controls or dealing with more complex issues, I think that you know the basics and then I also think that you should rely more on practice than on theoretics; although this time differently: I would take a working code (for example, a custom textbox doing this and that... there are plently of codes in internet), I would understand it and, only after that, would go deeper in theoretics. With "Design mode", I did understand the VS interface allowing you to create controls, as opposed to the pure code.

Comment: For example, the code in your link seems pretty good for what I meant. What I would do in your position, rather than getting the theoretical explanation of each single line, would be: executing this code, understanding how it works (by using it), starting to perform small modifications by my own, etc. And after getting some practice, going to a manual (cannot recommend any but I guess that shouldn't be too difficult to find one; MSDN provides lots of information) and understanding the theoretics behind what you have seen working. This would be, at least, the approach I would take.

Comment: "Design mode" not in VS but in your own application!
Please read carefully the above link
I suppose you never hear about this functionality

Comment: Yes, clear now. I have explained in my last comment what would be my approach anyway: start the learning by playing with a working code. This is all what I can say (I do understand that some people might prefer a different learning proceeding). Also the expression "design mode" I think that is a bit confusing as far as it is usually associated with what I initially referred: VS design mode.